# UL CSS Columns - Line up columns height to match if multiple lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I currently am using CSS columns, to create a 2 column layout for an unordered list.  Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="meta-data">
   <ul> 
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Case Study</strong> Case Study Here </li>        
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Sector</strong> Sector Here </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Client</strong> Client Here </li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Value</strong> Value Here </li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Programme Duration</strong> Programme Duration Here </li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Current Status</strong> Current Status Here </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.meta-data ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

This works fine. However, if any of the li content wrap onto 2 lines or more, it throws off the 2nd column bullet points so they're not all lined up horizontally...

For example:

```
Case Studies:  This goes onto       Value:  Value Here
two lines
                                    Programme Duration:  Duration here.
Sector:  Sector here. 
                                    Current Status:  Current Status here.
Client:   Client Here
```

This looks messy.

I'd rather it showed as:

```
Case Studies:  This goes onto       Value:  Value Here
two lines

Sector:  Sector here.               Programme Duration:  Duration here.

Client:   Client Here               Current Status:  Current Status here.
```

Is this easily possible with the CSS columns setup, or do I need to recode this a diff way?

Comment: use flex with flex-wrap but unfortunately you would need to do items 1 and 2 side by side instead of filling one column first and then moving to the next

Comment: I would think this is not possible using `columns`, but don't know for sure. You can achieve that kind of layout using `flexbox`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: That requirement is basically contradictory to how CSS columns work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way to do this using column property, you can use [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.meta-data ul {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-data">
   <ul> 
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Case Study</strong> Case Study Here Case Study HereCase Study</li>        
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Sector</strong> Sector Here </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Client</strong> Client Here </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Value</strong> Value Here </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Programme Duration</strong> Programme Duration Here  </li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i><strong>Current Status</strong> Current Status Here         </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```